How to resolve javax.script.ScriptException in my Kotlin project
I am working on a Kotlin project and need to use javax.script.ScriptException. However, I'm encountering an error stating that javax.script.ScriptException is unresolved, which means there is no built-in support for this in my project.
I've just set up this project and I'm not sure what is causing this issue. I have searched extensively on the internet but couldn't find a solution. Below is the content of my build.gradle(app) file and this is the gradle(plugins)!
I tried to add some dependencies like these:
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-common:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm-host:1.9.0")

or
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:1.9.0")

to see if they can solve my problem, but the issue persists and it still gives an "unresolved" error.
Could someone please help me understand why I can't use javax.script.ScriptException and how to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

your need install sdk java anda javax ok
Environment for windows or mack.
kotlin install sdk and switch android studio and install sdk android studio.
run project to android studio kotlin import first java and second kotlin.
main point :all library update sdk java and kotlin for Android studio

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
